# how to get node permalink in Drupal 8 programatically

Tags: drupal-8

I have created 5 articles in Drupal 8.
I am using the following code
Now I have 1 array of the node id's

> $node_storage->loadMultiple($nids);

So now how can I get the node permalink and the thumbnail size of the field_image? Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$link = '/node/' . $node_storage[0]->id();
$image = $node_storage[0]->get('field_image')->getValue();
$image = $node_storage[0]->get('field_image')->getValue()[0]['value'];
```

something like that should work

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I did it in a different way and it's working well.
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
$url_object = Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('entity.node.canonical', ['node' =>$node->get('nid')->value], $options);
    $node_permalink = $url_object->toString(); }